# Exception when calling Okta authentication

Tags: .net, okta, okta-api

I am trying to use Okta for authentication in my app which doesn't need SSO, just to authenticate the user details against Okta and then go on and check other systems if it fails. The API is a little sparse but I am trying the following

```
var oktaClient = new OktaClient("my-api-token", new Uri("https://mysubdomain.okta.com"));
var authClient = oktaClient.GetAuthClient();
var oktaResponse = authClient.Authenticate(username, password);
```

That last line is throwing an Okta.Core.OktaException. The details are:

```
Error making an HTTP request: One or more errors occurred.
Additional information: Error making an HTTP request: One or more errors occurred.
```